# Man pages for libvlc

Tags: c++, c, video, video-streaming, libvlc

I am not sure whether this question belongs here, pardon me if this is not the case.
Can you people give me pointers on where I could find the technical documentation of `libvlc`, and especially the followinf functions ?

```
void libvlc_playlist_pause( libvlc_instance *, libvlc_exception )
mtime_t libvlc_input_get_length( libvlc_input_t *, libvlc_exception )
mtime_t libvlc_input_get_time( libvlc_input_t *, libvlc_exception )
void libvlc_input_set_time( libvlc_input_t *, mtime_t , libvlc_exception )
float libvlc_input_get_position( libvlc_input_t *, libvlc_exception )
void libvlc_input_set_position( libvlc_input_t *, float , libvlc_exception )
void libvlc_set_rate( libvlc_input_t *, float rate, libvlc_exception )
float libvlc_get_rate( libvlc_input_t *, libvlc_exception )
libvlc_input_get_information( libvlc_input_t *, libvlc_exception )
```

In particular can you please explain how the `libvlc_playlist_pause` function works.

I am using this in my application to run a video stream. My video is running but since  the video file is coming over a network, I need to pause the player for a particular amount of time untill enough data are buffered.

With regards
Mawia

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for libvlc is [here](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc.html)